# Programatically render block with contextual links (in php)

Tags: blocks

I'm trying to find a solution to embed a drupal custom block using PHP. I found this snippet that works :

```
<?php
$block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('your_block_id');
$render = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block')->view($block);
print render($render);
?>
```

The problem is that this code directly render the block content, I don't have any contextual links for that block. My question is, how to render the whole block (including contextual links), exactly like if I added it in a region using the UI.

Thank you

Comment: That should do it, the contextual links are added in preprocess. Have you confirmed that when you add the same block into a region through the UI the contextual links are rendered?

Comment: Added thanks to the UI, the contextual links are rendered. It's when I try to render using php that contextual links are not added.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module to insert the 'local tasks' menu in your template file:

`{{ drupal_entity('block', 'THEME_local_tasks', check_access=true) }}`

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the tips, but I need to do it using php. I'm not on the template file to do that. I know this is not ideal, but I don't have choice.

Comment: So you can just use the function behind this twig function named drupalEntity in twig_tweak/src/TwigExtension.php.

Comment: The following function for twig tweak works like a charme by the way.

Answer (score 0):

This is an open issue. Block Content entities have no Contextual links when rendered outside of Block config entity: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2666578