# Contextual links in block disabled when using Twig Tweak and UUID

Tags: 8, theming, blocks

In my taxonomy-term--NAME.html.twig I use a reference field to load a 'block_content'.

```
{% for item in term.field_blocks %}
  {% set uuid =  item.entity.uuid.value %}
  {{ drupal_block('block_content:' ~ uuid) }}
{% endfor %}
```

The block is rendered correctly but without the 'contextual links' (quick edit on front-end).

When I look into the twig_tweak module, I see you can add an array with configuration options.

```
public function drupalBlock($id, array $configuration = [], $wrapper = TRUE) {

    $configuration += ['label_display' => BlockPluginInterface::BLOCK_LABEL_VISIBLE];

    /** @var \Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface $block_plugin */
    $block_plugin = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block')
      ->createInstance($id, $configuration);
    ...
}
```

Does anyone know how I can change the twig-rule to something like this:

```
{{ drupal_block('block_content:' ~ uuid, {show_contextual_links:true}) }}
```

I found this question, but that is not correct:
[Programatically render block with contextual links (in php)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/261097/programatically-render-block-with-contextual-links-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it like this:

```
<div data-quickedit-entity-id="block_content/1008" class="contextual-region" data-once="quickedit" data-quickedit-entity-instance-id="0">
  {{ drupal_contextual_links('block_content:block_content=1008:langcode:') }}
  {{ drupal_entity('block_content', 1008) }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `{{ drupal_entity('block_content', 'content_block_id') }}`, Drupal skips the block template, which contains the code for contextual links. If you use `{{ drupal_block('plugin_id') }}`, it will apply the block template, including title, links and other attributes.

If you look at the default block template in Classy (block.html.twig):

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'block',
    'block-' ~ configuration.provider|clean_class,
    'block-' ~ plugin_id|clean_class,
  ]
%}
<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
  {{ title_prefix }}
  {% if label %}
    <h2{{ title_attributes }}>{{ label }}</h2>
  {% endif %}
  {{ title_suffix }}
  {% block content %}
    {{ content }}
  {% endblock %}
</div>
```

The `{{ title_suffix }}` part contains the code that renders the contextual links.